# If Sunday then show Week rest else present in oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

Hi dear I am working in oracle reports I have a column `ATT_DATE` which have dates for the month next column I have :Day which I create function like this which gives me day

```
begin
  RETURN TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE, 'DAY');
end;
```

It gives me Day of the Date which present in :ATT_DATE
Now I wants to  make one more function which checks **SUNDAY** then gives me two these things like if Sunday than **Weekly Rest** else **Present** in :Status column  I write this code

```
function M_DAY2Formula return CHAR is
begin
  IF TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE, 'DAY') = 'SUNDAY' THEN
     RETURN 'WEEK REST';
  ELSE
     RETURN 'PRESENT';
  END IF;
end;
```

but it neve Takes Sunday it gives in all days Present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is about `TRIM`. See the following example:

```
SQL> with dates as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 10
  5    )
  6  select datum,
  7         to_char(datum, 'DAY') dan,
  8         to_char(datum, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language = english') dan2,
  9         --
 10         length(to_char(datum, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language = english')) len_dan2,
 11         --
 12         case when to_char(datum, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'SUNDAY' then 'Week rest'
 13              else 'Present'
 14         end status,
 15         --
 16         case when trim(to_char(datum, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language = english')) = 'SUNDAY' then 'Week rest'
 17              else 'Present'
 18         end status2
 19  from dates
 20  order by datum;

DATUM      DAN         DAN2        LEN_DAN2 STATUS    STATUS2
---------- ----------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------
15.02.2021 PONEDJELJAK MONDAY             9 Present   Present
16.02.2021 UTORAK      TUESDAY            9 Present   Present
17.02.2021 SRIJEDA     WEDNESDAY          9 Present   Present
18.02.2021 ČETVRTAK    THURSDAY           9 Present   Present
19.02.2021 PETAK       FRIDAY             9 Present   Present
20.02.2021 SUBOTA      SATURDAY           9 Present   Present
21.02.2021 NEDJELJA    SUNDAY             9 Present   Week rest
22.02.2021 PONEDJELJAK MONDAY             9 Present   Present
23.02.2021 UTORAK      TUESDAY            9 Present   Present
24.02.2021 SRIJEDA     WEDNESDAY          9 Present   Present

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

In other words:

- if your date language isn't English, you can't compare it to "SUNDAY" (that's `dan` in my example)
- if there's nothing wrong with the language, why the first `case` (the `status` column) doesn't work properly? Because of the **length** - see? No matter which day it it, length is `9` in all cases.
- therefore, `trim` the `DAY` value and then it works as expected

---

Or, in Reports Builder:

```
function M_DAY2Formula return CHAR is
begin
  IF trim(TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN     --> TRIM, here
     RETURN 'WEEK REST';
  ELSE
     RETURN 'PRESENT';
  END IF;
end;
```

Comment: its fine when we write in sql how can i write in report function

Comment: Exactly like that. TRIM. See edited answer.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand can u write that how i can put this i Know this is irritating for you but please help me thanks

Comment: I already wrote it. `IF trim(TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN  ...`

Comment: if i write like this it throw me error Identifier **trim** must be declared

Comment: Then you did something wrong. TRIM is a function, not an identifier.

Comment: Instead of Trim you can also use format `'fmDAY'`

Comment: `function M_DAY2Formula return CHAR is
begin
  IF trim(TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN
    RETURN 'WEEK REST';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'PRESENT';
  END IF;
end;` Without trim or fmDAY its compiled but not showed week rest in Sunday all column same **Present** @Littlefoot  @wernfried

Comment: Which Reports version do you use? I can't believe it doesn't support TRIM nor fmDAY ...

Comment: Do you pass a **string** instead of a `DATE` value?

Comment: @Littlefoot oracle report 6i

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit dear it returns Char so datatype must be char of function how to pass i mentioned above

Comment: Wernfried asked about :ATT_DATE datatype, not what function returns.

Comment: :ATT_DATE type data type is date

Comment: @Littlefoot and wernfried thanks both of you specially littlefoot u r so kind

Answer (score 0):

what code is work for me

```
function M_DAY3Formula return Char is
a varchar2(40);
B varchar2(40);
begin
  select RTRIM(to_char(:ATT_DATE,'DAY')) into a from dual;
    IF A = 'SUNDAY'
        THEN B := 'WEEK REST';
    ELSE B := 'PRESENT';
        END IF;
    return B;
end;
```